# Removing character elements from a vector

Tags: r, list, vector, character

I was trying to figure out how to remove several characters from a list (not one per one):

-First I converted my data.frame (single column) in a list `A` of characters with `A2[]<-lapply(A,as.character)`

-then I converted it to  `A3<-unlist(A2, recursive = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)` producing a vector which contains all the atomic components which occur in `A1`.

Finally I use `str_remove(A3, ".")` to remove, in this case, the points. See below:

```
     A1      A2      A3      A4      A5      A6      A7      A8      A9     A10 
    "*"     "*"     "*"     "*"     "*"     "*"     "*"     "*"     "*"     "*" 
    A11     A12     A13     A14     A15     A16     A17     A18     A19     A20 
    "*"   "=1-"   "*C:"     "I"     "."     "."     "."     "."     "."     "." 
    A21     A22     A23     A24     A25     A26     A27     A28     A29     A30 
    "."     "2"   "V7b"     "."     "."     "."     "."     "I"     "."     "."
```

The problem is that applying `str_remove()` other elements of the vector as "*" get lost. Is that normal?

```
 [1] ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""    
 [11] ""     "1-"   "C:"   ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""    
 [21] ""     ""     "7b"   ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""     ""
```

Is there a better way to do that? It is simply to remove "." of that column:

```
12     =1-
13     *C:
14      I
15      .
16      .
17      .
18      .
19      .
20      .
21      .
22      2
23    V7b
24      .
25      .
26      .
27      .
28      I
29      .
30      .
31      .
```

to get:

```
=1-
*C:
I
2
V7b
I
```

Comment: Most of what you do before using `str_remove` seems unnecessary. First you use `as.list` and then `unlist`? Why?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So, you mean that `unlist` could be done directly. I'll reformulate the question.

Comment: I don't even know why you need `unlist`. Can't you just do `A1[[1]]`?

Comment: I tried and it is not working.I need atomic c. to apply `str_remove`. However `as.list` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The period is a meta character (see [here](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/ItDT/HTML/node84.html)), so try escaping it like so-

```
str_remove(A3, “\\.”)
```

Edit:

You can remove multiple characters from a vector of arbitrary length with `str_remove_all`, which removes every match from the supply character vector. You can also supply `str_remove_all` *multiple patterns* to match at once, allowing you to do multiple operations with only one line of code.

```
library(stringr)
a <- c("hello. this. is. text","this. is. also. text","here. is. even. more. text")
remove_these <- c("\\.","text")
str_remove_all(a, paste(remove_these, collapse = "|"))
```

This returns:

```
"hello this is "     "this is also "      "here is even more "
```

Comment: Do you know if it can be applicable to more than one element-character? Or just recurring each time to the last vector the same option.

Comment: see my edit. is that what you mean? str_remove will remove the first match from each item in the character vector while str_remove_all will remove every match.

Comment: I mean e.g. that `str_remove_all(a, "\\." && "\\x")` ... I know that this doesn't work, but just in case I wanted to know how to evade repetitions.

Comment: ah, yes- great question, you can do that. see my edit.

Comment: Very witty! Obvious in some sense. Thank you,